# Can't get desktop shortcuts working

Tags: raspbian, desktop

I've tried everything to get my desktop shortcut working on my Pi for a `.py` script

The script I wrote is located on a USB drive at location:

```
/media/pi/SMT_DATA/SMT2.py
```

I'm using Berryconda 3.6 located at `/home/pi/berryconda3`, I ran `chmod +x SMT2.py` and added `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the top of my script file

The desktop entries I've tried are:

This one spins but nothing happens

```
[Desktop Entry]<br>
Type=Application<br>
Name=SMT Program<br>
Exec=lxterminal /media/pi/SMT_DATA/SMT2.py<br>
StartupNotify=true<br>
Icon=/media/pi/SMT_DATA/files/SMT.ico<br>
```

This one gives me invalid desktop entry

```
[Desktop Entry]<br>
Type=Application<br>
Name=SMT Program<br>
Exec=/media/pi/SMT_DATA/SMT2.py<br>
StartupNotify=true<br>
Icon=/media/pi/SMT_DATA/files/SMT.ico<br>
```

Is there anything that I'm missing?